# How to work with ASCII non-printable characters using awk

Tags: database, awk

First using `cat` command `cat -v -e -t <my_file>` I have this load file.DAT with some non-printable ASCII characters.

```
þBEGNUMþ^TþENDNUMþ^TþBEGATTþ^TþENDATTþ^T^M$
þTM00000001þ^TþTM00000001þ^TþTM00000001þ^TþTM00000001þ^M$
```

How do I use awk to work with data and remove last column? `þENDATTþ^T^` so that output becomes:

```
þBEGNUMþ^TþENDNUMþ^TþBEGATTþM$
þTM00000001þ^TþTM00000001þ^TþTM00000001þM$
```

Note that my delimiters is from a [Concordance database](https://help.lexisnexis.com/litigation/ac/cn_classic/managing_data_files.htm)

Comma □ (ASCII 20)

Quote þ (ACSII 254)

New Line ® (ASCII 174)

Comment: What's your field separator?

Comment: Comma □ (ASCII 20)

Comment: @Cyrus - This might be more helpful. 
Field separator is U+0014 [DEVICE CONTROL FOUR]

Comment: Please disregard, I was able to resolve using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out using

`awk -F'\024' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS; ORS = "\n"} {$33=""; sub(/\024$/, ""); print $0}' tmp.dat > final.dat`